# "ent: constraint failed: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" get more verbose error output

Tags: go, logging, error-handling, ent

Logging error coming after failed insert to db using `ent` shows:

`ent: constraint failed: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`.

Is there a way to get more verbose formatting of the error, e.g. `FOREIGN KEY` that wasn't set?

I'm using below code for logging the error:

```
import (
   "github.com/labstack/gommon/log"
)

...
err := // some failed insert to db
if err != nil {
   log.Errorf("Error is %v", err)
}
...
```

`err` doesn't seem to provide any relevant methods.